# How to make a self-updating feed, like facebook?

Tags: javascript, html, web, e-commerce

I am making an e-commerce website, but I want customers to have to refresh the website every time I put up a new product, I want it to update itself as customers scroll through products.
here's the current code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Demo site</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">website</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex" role="search">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"/>
              </svg></button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div id="products">
        
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

anyone who knows how to do this please help

Comment: If you're new to stackoverflow please look at how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. That said you will first need a database to store all the items, connect it establish a websockit connection if needed and display the items

Comment: I voted to close this question because there are usually hundreds of ways to implement a feature; too many to enumerate here. Furthermore, a full answer to any one of them could require many pages or even a full book. Rather than asking for an approach, [edit] your question to focus on a more specific problem you encounter when you actually try to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you wil need a database to store the products (if you don't have). And from there you would have different approaches for a solution. One of the could be some javascript that sends a request to an endpoint every once in a while in order to check if there is new posts available. This would also require you to have some sort of API integration.

Alternatively you could use [socket.io](https://socket.io/) or other packages in order to use websockets. This would also require a server, but this would be the more accurate way to do it, as its in "real time". With the websockets you would make the server send a signal through the websockets to all the connected clients that there is new content available, and from there do stuff to get the new data.

Comment: i dont know how to code with socket